# The count is not updated after changes

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-2.2

I have added a menu item to the default .NET Core SPA template `nav-menu.component.html` file like this:

```
<li [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]'>
    <a [routerLink]='["/fetch-data"]' (click)='collapse()'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Requests ({{count}})
    </a>
</li>
```

It shows the requests's count that is fetched from server inside the parenthesis. I have initialized the count in my ts file like this:

```
export class NavMenuComponent {

count: number;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {

var url = this.baseUrl + "api/request/TheCount/";
this.http.get<number>(url).subscribe(result => {
  this.count = result;
}, error => console.error(error));

}
```

And `TheCount` method is simply fetching the count of requests from server like this:

```
[HttpGet("TheCount")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TheCount()
{
    var count = await GetRequestsCount();

    return new JsonResult(count, new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    });
}
```

This works just fine and it shows the count inside parenthesis as per expectation. But the problem is, when I will delete one of the requests from another components, the count variable in `nav-menu.component` isn't updated and so I have to refresh the site in order to get the refreshed count again. So my question is, is there any way, the count will be refresh automatically after changes?

Comment: You can try to watch the changes with the onChanges Lifecycle hook in Angular. read more here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: The scope of count is limited to current component and you are fetching it once in constructor so it won't update when count changed in other component. I would recommend create a service that maintain and manipulate request counts. Use that service in both of the components through DI. This should solve your problem

Comment: @SureshPatidar I am new to Angular. Can you please provide an answer and let me know, how?

Comment: @Napinator I am new to Angular. Can you please provide an answer and let me know, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is sample template

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
                import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
                import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

                @Injectable()
                export class CountService {

        count: number;

          public observalbleCount: BehaviorSubject<number>;


                  constructor(
                    protected httpClient: HttpClient) {
        this.count= 0;
                    this.observalbleCount = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.count);
                  }

                  getCount(): Observable<number> {

return new Observable((observer) => {

this.httpClient.get<number>(url).subscribe(result => {
                        this.count = result 
                        this.setCount(result);
                        observer.next(result);
                      }, error => console.error(error));
                      });



                  }

                  public setCount(data: number) {
        this.count=data;
                    this.observalbleCount.next(data);
                  }

                }
```

Actual component

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { CountService } from './';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class NavComponent implements OnDestroy {
    count: number;
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private countService: CountService) {
        // subscribe to home component messages
        this.countService.GetCount().subscribe((data) => {
          this.count = data;
        });
this.subscription = this.countService.observalbleCount.subscribe((data) => {
          this.count = data;
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: So after add/remove requests in another component I should call the `countService.getCount` manually again, right?

Comment: No need as you have initialized in constructor it will take care. this (this.countService.getCount().subscribe((data) => {) line should be in  component constructor   follow this link for more https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: This should be in both component (navmenu and deleterequest) or just navmenu enough?

Comment: Both the component so in your case the navmenu would just want get the data so use getCount() and deleterequest component would use setCount() method you need to send the updated count to this method so that it is reflected or else you can implement your own logic where setCount will call a api to deleterequest and get updated count .

Comment: Everything is OK, just please let me know why this line doesn't executed? `this.count = data;` My service is called successfully with this line `this.countService.getCount().subscribe` but it then doesn't work in `subscribe`. Why?

Comment: Updated my answer please check  use get count to get the count at first you can implement this logic as you like just make sure that you set this.count

Comment: Please update your answer. it won't compile, where did you called `getCount`?? Also it doesn't return anything!

Comment: updated sorry i dont have compiler handy , getCount() you can call in navmanu constructor so what happens is getCount will get the count once and whenever setCount method is called it the this.countService.observalbleCount.subscribe will be invoked which will change the count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193881/discussion-between-shantanu-and-j-p).

Comment: Please update your code and show me how should I call the `getCount` and `this.countService.observalbleCount.subscribe` in my nav.component. I just confused with this part!

Comment: Udpated with sample component

Comment: Shouldn't `observalbleCount: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>();` contains count as parameter? like this: `observalbleCount: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.count);`

Comment: I just have another question: what if, I have more than `Subscription` variable in my navmenu component? Currently I had to define 3 separate variable for each of them but I believe there should be some easier way to achieve the same.

Comment: dont know how this will span out but you can try declaring a class and updating that class values new BehaviorSubject<{{class}}>(this.{{class}})

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you delete/add the count should be updated.

you add your code in service

```
 this.http.get<number>(url).subscribe(result => {
  this.count = result;
}, error => console.error(error));

}
```

then use Subject or BehaviorSubject on a particular variable (count) of that service

so that whenever the data changes it will call the service method and return the count

Comment: Thanks. Please provide more details. What is service and how should I change my code?

Comment: @J.P added a new answer please check